# Unexpected behavior with POSIXct datetimes under diff

Tags: r, date, datetime, time-series, posix

When diff() is applied to POSIXct datetimes, one gets unexpected result. The unit of the differences is not always the same.

On hourly increment POSIXct datetimes, diff() works as expected. If the hours are continuous, diff gives you the difference in hour, as seen below.

```
beg = ISOdatetime(2016, 11, 6, 1, 0 ,0, tz="Americ/Los_Angeles")
end = ISOdatetime(2016, 11, 7, 23, 0 ,0, tz="Americ/Los_Angeles")
dte = seq(from=beg, to=end, by="hour")
del = diff(dte)
table(del)
del
  1 
 46
```

If there are gaps, the result is still in hour, which makes sense.

```
dte = dte[-4]
del = diff(dte)
table(del)
 del
 1  2 
44  1
```

Now, here is the interesting behavior.

```
dte1 = sort(c(dte, dte[10]))
del = diff(dte1)
table(del)
del
 0 3600 7200 
 1   44    1
```

Here I added a duplicate hour, and all of the sudden, the diff unit is now in second.

Is this a bug?

Comment: It might be an infelicity but since the units are reported correctly if you look at `dput(del)` it can hardly be considered a bug.

Comment: Maybe only if you consider daylight savings time a bug in human society, which is certainly defensible. (I'm assuming the odds of this difference not being related to the fact that this time period hits DST are very low.)

Comment: @joran Not sure why does it have to do with DST?

Comment: It's the behavior of `difftime` with `units = "auto"`, which is the default for subtracting datetimes.

Comment: Just seemed like and unlikely coincidence, that's all.

Comment: @joran Well, I specifically chose the DST crossover date and it actually didn't breakdown. So, that's not about DST at all.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to pass a `units` parameter to `diff`, but you can reconstruct it with `difftime`: `difftime(dte1[-1], dte1[-length(dte1)], units = 'hours')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `units<-` function for difftime objects:

```
> units(del) <- 'hours'
> table(del)
del
 0  1 
 1 46
```

The `?difftime` help page says:

> If units = "auto", a suitable set of units is chosen, the largest possible (excluding "weeks") in which all the absolute differences are greater than one.

So perhaps the logic of the function got sidetracked by the 0 value in your case and the units got set to seconds.

Comment: I like your answer; however, as @allstaire pointed out, it's not possible to pass a `units` parameter to `diff`, so this requires an extra line of code, and the trick must be learned outside of the official doc.

Comment: I'm not sure what implied criticism is being made. I suggested setting the `units` parameter with a documented function, and alistaire suggests using `difftime` (rather than `diff.difftime`) a a method of allowing the units to be set: `difftime(tail(dte1,-1), head(dte1,-1) ,units="hour")`. Both seem reasonable (and "inside" the documentation), and I'd say my suggestion is slightly more "compact", in the sense of the coder not needing to construct 2 shorter vectors. His would be more general in allowing a lag argument.

Comment: Yea I'm going to roll my own custom `diff` for POSIXt. Your suggestion is good.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the source for `diff.POSIXt`, it contains the code

```
r <- r[i1] - r[-length(r):-(length(r) - lag + 1L)]
```

where `r` is the POSIXct sequence and `i1` is defined by

```
i1 <- -seq_len(lag)
```

which if the `lag` parameter is the default of 1, will just be -1. Thus, `diff(dte1)` is equivalent to

```
dte1[-1L] - dte1[-length(dte1):-(length(dte1) - 1L + 1L)]
```

which you can simplify to

```
dte1[-1L] - dte1[-length(dte1)]
```

If you look at `?difftime`, you see that

> Subtraction of date-time objects gives an object of this class, by
>   calling difftime with units = "auto".

Calling `difftime` with `units = "auto"` determines units by

> If units = "auto", a suitable set of units is chosen, the largest
>   possible (excluding "weeks") in which all the absolute differences are
>   greater than one.

which can vary. If you want particular units, you can reconstruct the operation with `difftime` directly:

```
difftime(dte1[-1], dte1[-length(dte1)], units = 'hours')

## Time differences in hours
##  [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
## [47] 1 1
```